# Join files by name with S3 Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I'm trying to make S3 Athena read data from two files in two S3 buckets.

Input record looks like:

```
{
    "column_1": "data1",
    "column_2": "data2",
    "column_3": "data3",
    "column_4": "data4",
    "column_5": "data5",
}
```

Then system splits it into 2 files and save to 2 buckets like this:

**s3://bucket_main/data/file_id.json**

```
{
    "column_1": "data1",
    "column_2": "data2",
    "column_3": "data3",
}
```

**s3://bucket_secondary/data/file_id.json**

```
{
    "column_4": "data4",
    "column_5": "data5",
}
```

It uses same unique filepath `data/file_id.json` in every bucket, so we can easily track both parts. I wonder how to make S3 Athena read both files and present them as a single record.

So far I've create two glue crawlers to parse buckets data and I can see two tables in glue data catalog: `main_data` and `secondary_data`. I'd prefer to have single table in glue data catalog if possible.

I can add extra ID field to both files, but it seems redundant as S3 filepath is ID by itself.

Answer (score 0):

A table in Amazon Athena cannot exist in two locations.

However, you could use [`CREATE VIEW`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-view.html) to join the two tables together via:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2
```

Using the View would then be the same as querying from both locations.